# Apache http server drops connection every 60 seconds

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I have an Apache HTTP web server that is load balancing for two tomcat instances using mod_jk.  Every 60 seconds it seems like it the http server loses connection with the tomcat instance, but immediately reconnects.  Is this something that can be turned off?

When I connect directly to one of the tomcat instances I never drop connection.  Only through the http server.

Comment: Please post your `<Connector>` configuration from Tomcat and your worker configuration from (probably) `workers.properties`. While posting those, take a look at the documentation for both, paying particular attention to those items which control the *timeouts*.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the value of the [Timeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) directive in your httpd.conf file. The default value is 60.

Comment: I noticed that if I lower that value it will drop connection more often.  However if I set the TimeOut to something higher, like 120, it will still drop every 60 seconds.  Im using XAMPP's Apache 2.4 server.  Are there any default modules that are loaded that would override this directive?

Comment: I don't know about any module that overrides the Timeout directive. But if you are using mod_proxy you could also check [ProxyTimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout).

Comment: If using ProxyTimeout, be aware that the default proxy.conf sets a timeout of 60 seconds using this directive, so if you place the ProxyTimeout directive before `Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf"`, it will be overriden.